# Loop Within Not Assigning Array Values Read From a File

Tags: arrays, vb.net, for-loop, streamreader

I've run into an issue that I cannot understand at all since it doesn't make sense why it's happening. I'm reading values from an input notepad file which contains numbers. For each line, the numbers separated by a gap  (" ") are assigned to a textbox. While reading, all of my lines are working completely fine except for one specific case.

This case contains 2 numbers, each representing the number of a specific type of item. This is how the code goes right now:

```
While Not filereader.EndofStream
  Dim NumberofItems = {NumType1, NumType2}
  Dim currentline As String
  currentline = filereader.ReadLine()
  currentline = currentline.Trim(" "c)
  Dim InputArray() As String = currentline.Split(" "c)

  ...... 'Other lines being read correctly

  For i=0 to Math.Min(NumberofItems.Length -1, InputArray.Length -1)
     NumberofItems(i).Text = InputArray(i)
  Next
End While
```

This only assigns the first value of the array correctly (out of the two). However if I change this to be:

```
NumberofItems(0).Text = InputArray(0)
NumberofItems(1).Text = InputArray(1)
```

It works perfectly fine, which I don't understand since this is essentially the loop but longer. 
I've rechecked my textbox names  and my input file, I've checked the value of the .Lengths as well as the return of the Math.Min - they are all correct. I've even replaced the loop to be:

```
For i=0 to 1 'Since I know there are only two numbers
       NumberofItems(i).Text = InputArray(i)
Next
```

This still does not work.

Does anyone have any idea about what I might be doing wrong here/why this is not working? I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint at `NumberofItems(i).Text = InputArray(i)`? That's the first thing that should be done then you can check the value of `InputArray(i)` when `i = 1`.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I added a breakpoint to the line. It is currently giving me a count of 1 for break always, even though it is supposed to be 2.

Comment: What's the value of both `NumberofItems.Length` and `InputArray.Length`? And what happens when you use `0 To 1` forcing the loop to run twice?

Comment: NumberofItems.Length and InputArray.Length both give a value of 2. If I run the loop through `0 to 1`, it still provides only the first value (for i=0) and not the second one (for i=1). Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you saying that when you use `For i = 0 To 1`, the loop only runs once? I'm not asking how many values it "provides". I'm asking how many times does it run?

Comment: Yes, even if I use from `For i = 0 To 1` and I run the program, the breakpoint has a total hit count of 1.

Comment: Where exactly in your program are you running this code? Are you sure there are no exceptions being swallowed? Check the Debug window to make sure.

Comment: Try making the last line of the loop like this `Next i`.

Comment: The way you describe it, the code is simply not doing what it should so something somewhere must be corrupt. I suggest that you create a new project and isolate just that functionality and see if the same thing happens. That's what you should pretty much always do in cases like this. Create a test project and test just the functionality at issue. If it works then that would suggest that your project is broken. If it still doesn't work then that would suggest that your system is broken. We can test the same basic project with the same data to see whether we see the same behaviour.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I'm running under a button click that opens the program at the very start of the code. I'll double check the exceptions.

Comment: @preciousbetine That didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I'll check that, thanks for the suggestion!